# How does ABP insert value in an SQL SERVER identity column

Tags: abp

I'm working on a DataSeeder program in ABP and needed to insert static values to identity columns. I have a method that does the SET IDENTITY_INSERT [table] ON/OFF and use it to turn on or off before and after I seed the tables. Is there a built in method in [ABP Framework](https://www.abp.io/) that does the same thing?